# Параллельное выполнение запросов

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, асинхронность, asyncio

У меня есть 2 асинхронных запроса. Я хочу, чтобы они выполнялись в параллель друг другу. Поясню.Я хочу, чтобы к моменту, когда я сделаю `await resp_a`, и `fetch(a)`, и `fetch(b)`  уже скорее всего отработали и мне не потребуется ожидать ответа от сервера?

```
resp_a = fetch(a) 
resp_b = fetch(b) 
time.sleep(long_time)
await resp_a
await resp_b
```

В реальности, после выполнения `fetch(a)`, запроса к серверу не происходит. Происходит он лишь в момент времени `await resp_a`. По крайней мере, так происходит в дебаггере.

---

Есть 2 запроса к разным сервисам. Считаем, что они достаточно тяжёлые. Хочется, не дожидаться их ответа, а выполнять их в параллель.

```
async def fetch():
    print('2')
    ...

print('1')
resp_a = fetch(a)  # Тяжёлый запрос 1
print('3')
resp_b = fetch(b)  # Тяжёлый запрос 2 
time.sleep(long_time)  # Тяжёлая обработка. Где-то здесь, в параллель с этой тяжёлой обработкой запрос 1 обработался и запрос 2 обработался.
await resp_a  
await resp_b
```

Как я говорил выше, если выполнять в дебаггере, я получу:

> 1 
>   2
>   3

Без

> 1
>   3
>   2

Comment: Следует выполнить без дебаггера. Тогда всё работает

Comment: Кажется что работает - на самом деле нет.

Comment: @eri почему?   .   .

Comment: странный дебагер, как называется? 1 3 2 2 должно быть

Comment: Обычный питонящий, который идёт в стандартном наборе под ubuntu.

Comment: pdb который? или ещё что?

Comment: @eri. Никогда не задавался вопросом, как он называется. Пользовался и пользовался.

Comment: ну как-то же его запускаешь)

Comment: @eri я его запускаю всегда через IDE PyCharm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resp_a = fetch(a) 
resp_b = fetch(b)
```

Не выполняет запросов, а только создает структуру асинхронных вызовов. awaitable объект.

Начать его выполнять его надо присоединить к loop. Слово await  делает из awaitable future b выполняет все запланированные future.

Чтоб выполнить их параллельно следует использовать asyncio.gather или asyncio.wait, иногда случае enshure_future

## gather - выполняет оба запроса конкурентно

```
result_a, result_b = await asyncio.gather(resp_a,resp_b) # выполняет запросы
```

## wait - запускает оба запроса, возвращает первый или все

```
done, pending = await asyncio.wait([resp_a,resp_b],return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)

first = await done
done, pending = await asyncio.wait(pending,return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
second = await done
```

## asyncio.ensure_future - запускает запрос

```
resp_a = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(a))
resp_b = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(b))
```

Запрос запущен, но ещё не отправлен.

```
time.sleep(long_time)
```

всё ещё не запущен, time.sleep блокирует выполнение запросов

```
await asyncio.sleep(long_time)
```

вот тут запустятся все три: resp_b,resp_a, sleep и ждем sleep

```
await resp_a
await resp_b
```

Дожидаемся resp_a, а потом resp_b.

Comment: Да, я понимаю. Я спрашивал это с точки зрения aiohttp. И там проблема была в дебаггере. В asyncio, вероятно, да. Нужно делать так, как вы написали. Но это не самая удобная вещь, которую я встречал

Comment: напиши что хочется сделать - я опишу как сделать красиво

Comment: Добавил в вопрос