# Одновременное выполнение асинхронных функций python

Tags: python, асинхронность

У меня есть код, вида:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def waiter() -> None:
    await cook('Паста', 8)
    await cook('Салат Цезарь', 3)
    await cook('Отбивные', 16)
    какой-то код

async def cook(order: str, time_to_prepare: int) -> None:
    print(f'Новый заказ: {order}')
    await  time.sleep(time_to_prepare)
    print(order, '- готово')

asyncio.run(waiter())
```

Подскажите, смогу ли я выполнять три функции cook параллельно, запустив функции и начав выполнять код далее, если да, то как?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Параллельное выполнение запросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1128319/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: К сожалению, нет. Мне надо запустить функции, и не дожидаясь их конца, запустить код под ними